# Is this use of offsetof guaranteed to be correct?

Tags: c++, offsetof

I have read that offsetof macro is commonly implemented as:

```
#define offsetof(st, m) \
    ((size_t)&(((st *)0)->m))
```

And according to Wikipedia there is debate about whether this is undefined behavior because it may be dereferencing a pointer. I have a buffer of information that I need to send to different places, but the buffer only takes up part of the struct. I was wondering if the following is guaranteed to give the correct size of my struct up to the end of the buffer, the last member.

```
struct PerObjBuffer
{
    mat4 matrix;
    mat4 otherMatrix;
    vec4 colour;
    int sampleType = 0;

    size_t getBufferSize() { return offsetof(PerObjBuffer, sampleType) + sizeof(sampleType); }
    void sendToGPU() { memcpy(destination, this, getBufferSize()); }
    String shaderStringCode =

        R"(layout(binding = 2, std140) uniform perObjectBuffer
    {
        mat4 WVPMatrix;
        mat4 worldMatrix;
        vec4 perObjColour;
        int texSampleFormat;
        };
    )";
```

}

If the use of offsetof isn't a good idea, what's the best way to do what I want to do?

Edit: What about sizeof(PerObjBuffer) - sizeof(String)? Would I have to take into account padding issues?

Comment: `offsetof` is implemented by standard library -> it's usage (by itself) safe.

Comment: That should work on any valid pointer of the right type. What's wrong with dereferencing a valid pointer?

Comment: &(((st *)0)->m) I guess this is the part Wikipedia was saying there was debate about?

Comment: @KamilCuk It's used as a macro? I don't access it with std:: ?

Comment: @KamilCuk From cpp preference.com Notes

offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support: GCC, LLVM.

Comment: `It's used as a macro?` Yes, it's specified to be a macro. `I don't access it with std:: ?` No, you do not, it's a macro. You seem to be concerned how something is implemented - as a user who uses the language, you do not care. People who implement the standard library have to implement them in a way that works. How it's implemented.. it's up to them.

Comment: @Zebrafish You seem to have a lot of questions but you rarely accept any answers. Why is that?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I usually leave answers for a couple of days in case others come along. I have accepted some some straightaway though.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo You're right, I haven't kept on top of it. I leave it for a while and then I forget. I'll go through some of them now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard specifies behaviors of things, not how are they implemented. The implementation part is left to implementators - people who write compilers and libraries - and they have to implement things in a way they *work* in a way specified by the standard. If that implementation of standard library has by itself undefined behavior is irrelevant - it has to work with specified compiler, so specific compiler will interpret it in a way it has the behavior implementators want. Undefined behavior means that *the standard* specifies no requirement on the behavior of code. Your compiler documentation may specify additional requirements specifying behaviors of code that according to the standard are undefined - thus the code may be undefined by the standard and be perfectly fine and reasonable on a *specific compiler* that is required/written to interpret it in that way.

C++ language uses macros from C language when proper `#include` is used. The C standard says [C99 7.17p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.17p3):

```
 The macros are [...] and

        offsetof(type, member-designator)

which expands to an integer constant expression that has type size_t, the value of which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by member-designator), from the beginning of its structure (designated by type). The type and member designator shall be such that given

        static type t;

then the expression &(t.member-designator) evaluates to an address constant. (If the specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.)
```

As a user of the language you *do not care* how it's implemented. If you use a standard compliant compiler, whatever it does behind the scenes, it should result in the behavior specified by the standard. Your usage of `offsetof(PerObjBuffer, sampleType)` is valid - having `static PerObjBuffer t;` then `&(t.member-sampleType)` evaluates to address constant - so `offsetof(PerObjBuffer, sampleType)` evaluates to integer constant expression. You like *do not care* how the compiler arrives at the result - it can use dark magic to do it - what matters it that compiler does it and the result represents the offset in bytes. (I think the famous example is `memcpy` - it's not possible to implement `memcpy` in standard compliant way, yet the function... exists).

Still, I fear that other parts of your code will be very invalid. The `memcpy` will most probably result in undefined behavior - you will copy padding between members and you seem to want to send that to some hardware location. In any case, I advise to do extensive research on lifetime and representation of C++ objects, on padding within structures, types of objects (ie. `POD`/standard layout/trivial) and how to work with them (ie. when it's ok to use `mem*` functions/placement new/`std::launder`).